# Groovy & Jax-ws: @WebMethod annotation ignored

Tags: groovy, jax-ws, web-services

I recently found an example on implementing a We3bService with groovy and jax-ws:
the problem is that the @webmethod annotation seems to be ignored.

This is the source code of the groovy script:

```
import javax.jws.soap.*
import javax.jws.*
import javax.xml.ws.*
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Book {
    String name
    String author
}
@WebService (targetNamespace="http://predic8.com/groovy-jax/")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
class BookService{

    @WebMethod
    def add(Book book){
        println "Name of the book: ${book.name}"
    }
}

Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9000/book", new BookService())
```

and this is the exception caught:
Caught: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: 
runtime modeler error: SEI BookService has method **setProperty** annotated as BARE but it has more than one parameter bound to body. This is invalid. Please annotate the method with annotation: @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
    at wstest.run(wstest.groovy:21)

Comment: I know this was ages ago, but have you actually solved this issue, I'm getting the same error but not sure what to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't ignore your `@WebMethod`. If it does you wouldn't see any message about 'Bared' and 'Wrapped'.

Try to change `def` return type with `void`.

Comment: If a class is annotated just with the @WebService and with non @WebMethod annotation I think that jax-ws try to expose all the methods of the class. If the annotation @WebMethod is present jax-ws tries to expose just the annotated methods. If I am correct the exception thrown is referred to the method "setProperty", wich I think is part of the groovy object implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to JAX-WS (JSR-224) specification, if used at type level `@SoapBinding` annotation specifies the WSDL mapping style for all methods in the class. This include of those that Groovy adds. Moving `@SoapBinding` to method level should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question: [wsimport how to create web service client from WSDL for http:binding GET/POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583767/wsimport-how-to-create-web-service-client-from-wsdl-for-httpbinding-get-post)
is the same problem. In your case you have the method **setProperty** in the class BookService and based on the error, this has more than one parameter. Make sure if you really need this method in your service implementation, if it is so, mark this method as private (in the case that you use this method from your service operation)