# wsimport how to create web service client from WSDL for http:binding GET/POST

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I have wsdl and I create classes with wsimport tool. Everything is going ok for SOAP messages but for http:binding GET/POST I get error. Part of the WSDL follows:

```
<wsdl:binding name="DictServiceHttpPost" type="tns:DictServiceHttpPost"> 
    <http:binding verb="POST" /> 
...
...
...
<wsdl:port name="DictServiceHttpGet" binding="tns:DictServiceHttpGet"> 
      <http:address location="http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx" /> 
    </wsdl:port> 
    <wsdl:port name="DictServiceHttpPost" binding="tns:DictServiceHttpPost"> 
      <http:address location="http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx" /> 
</wsdl:port>
```

wsimport generates classes, for SOAP port its working but for GET/POST but when I use them, I receive error.

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: SEI invoker.DictServiceHttpPost has method match annotated as BARE but it has more than one parameter bound to body. This is invalid. Please annotate the method with annotation: @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.validateDocBare(RuntimeModeler.java:1247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocBareMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:1236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:609)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:401)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:675)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:92)
    at invoker.DictService.getDictServiceHttpPost(DictService.java:124)
    ... 29 more
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: SEI invoker.DictServiceHttpPost has method match annotated as BARE but it has more than one parameter bound to body. This is invalid. Please annotate the method with annotation: @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, the problem was that I had a public method in the service implementation, that had more than one parameter but this method was not a service operation. Services marked with: SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE should only have public methods with only one parameter. My solution was mark this method as private since I was using it from one public method of the service (operation).

Make sure you don't have any public method in your service implementation that has more than one parameter.